strange use of уволитъ
From РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ 1924:

Не могутъ милліоны людей жить будущимъ государствомъ; у каждаго изъ
нихъ тысячи нуждъ, которые должны быть удовлетворены сегодня, иначе ни
у нихъ, ни у всего народа и будущаго не будетъ. Словомъ, сіонизмъ не
уволитъ евреевъ, но онъ несомнѣнно духовно отводитъ ихъ отъ страны,
гдѣ жили ихъ предки, гдѣ сами они родились и живутъ, гражданами
которой они состоятъ, съ жизнью которой и ихъ жизнь многообразно
связана

уволитъ here doesn't correspond to the dictionary definition of the word, "to discharge, to dismiss, to fire, to sack". Could it mean "to absolve them of their duty of loyalty to the Russian state"?

I almost sure there is a misprint. "Уводит" seems must be there.

Уволить used to have several meanings, variations to a common theme, that have almost died out by now: "set free," "rid (someone)," "dismiss," "let go," "spare," etc.
In modern Russian, these meanings are served by the verbs отпустить, освободить, and избавить. Even these days, освободить от должности is a fancy way of saying "to fire", and увольте and избавьте are synonymous interjections meaning "spare me (something)"
Here are some examples:


Итак, не может господин уволить (= освободить) селянина своего от Государственных податей, от наказания за преступления, заставить жениться на родне и в посты есть мясо. [А. Н. Радищев. Описание моего владения (1800-1801)]
Я никакой любви вашей не предпочитаю мое отечество и я вам чувствительнейшею обязан благодарностию за вами оказанные мне ласки, но прошу меня уволить (= отпустить) в мое королевство». [Сказка об Остромоносе-королевиче (1794-1795)]
Увольте (= избавьте) меня от такого дела, которого я в натуре не вижу, а потому и вообразить не умею. [Я. П. Козельский. Рассуждения двух индийцев Калана и Ибрагима о человеческом познании (1788)]


It's hard to tell exactly which one of these meanings is being used in the book, but most probably, it's either "let go" or "set free".

Well, the second example seems to explain the case in question. Nowadays "уволить" has no this meaning anymore (and I never encountered it anywhere). But I see origins of this word and could add that in the second example "уволить в моё королевство" has quite explicit nuance of "will/wish" and means "give me a freedom and let me return to my kingdom".

УВО́ЛИТЬ, уволю, уволишь, совер., кого-что.

(несовер. увольнять). Освободить (на время или окончательно) от выполнения каких-нибудь обязанностей. «От должности увольте вы меня!» Некрасов. Уволить с военной службы. Уволить в отпуск. Уволить в отставку. Уволить по сокращению штатов. Уволить из школы.
Освободить, избавить от чего-нибудь (неприятного; употр. обычно в форме просьбы; разг.). «Увольте нас от своего посещения… сейчас же.» А.Островский. «- Выкушайте еще чашечку! - Нет, увольте!» А.Островский.

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.
I can see that you take into consideration only the first meaning.
If I were you, I would consider the second one.
Освободить, избавить от чего-то неприятного.
To liberate from something unpleasant.
